# Deny taking screenshots in Kivy Python under Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, screenshot

I have a problem: nowhere is described how to deny permission to take screenshots in Kivy under Android.
In python-for-android and buildozer documentations is nothing about it.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: You'll need to read the java doc to see how to do it. Also note that you can't really prevent people taking pictures of your UI.

Comment: @inclement, I know how to do that in Java, it's pretty easy to turn off opportunity to take screenshots and record screen on operational level. Java isn't connected with kivy python by the way.

Comment: Java is in fact closely connected to Kivy on Android, it is normal to call the java apis using pyjnius. If you know how to do it with an api call in java, this is what you should do in Kivy.